# ¿Como puedo usar un view de sql server en asp.net core 2?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-core

hice una vista en sql server  de varias tablas que uso muy concurrentes entre si, mi problema es que en asp.net core 2 solo puedo usar las tablas de mi base con linq o EF a partir de un contexto y sus modelos que genero con Scaffold-DbContext, ¿Como podría utilizar estas vistas?

Answer (score 1):

Bueno tendrias que hacerlo manual, lo primero es crear el modelo, luego agregarlo en el context.cs como están las otras tablas.

Ejemplo

```
public class Nombre_vista
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Nombre { get; set; }
public string Apellido { get; set; }

}
```

Agregar al context

```
public virtual DbSet<Nombre_vista> Nombre_vista { get; set; }
```

Luego en el metodo OnModelCreating

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

modelBuilder.Entity<Nombre_vista>(entity => { entity.HasKey(e => e.Id); });

}
```

De esa forma debe de funcionar, asi lo hice la ultima vez.

Answer (score 1):

Scaffold-DbContext no toma las vistas de SQL Server.

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

1. Crea la vista
2. Dicha vista solo debe contener referencia a una clave primaria sino te dará un error "requires a primary key to be defined". Esto seguramente puede ser una restricción para tu vista que impida aplicar esta solución.
3. Desde .net vas a tener que crear la clase que representa la vista y agregarla al DbContext manualmente.

Ejemplo:

Tengo la vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego el modelo creado manualmente, no con el comando dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold

```
public class VistaT1T2
{
    public int Id1 { get; set; }
    public string T1Desc { get; set; }
    public string T2Desc { get; set; }
}
```

Y en el DbContext tambien manualmente agregar

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<VistaT1T2>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Id1)
                .HasColumnName("id1")
                .ValueGeneratedNever();

            entity.Property(e => e.T1Desc)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("t1Desc")
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.T1Desc)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("t2Desc")
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);
        });
```

Luego en el controller (API)

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class VistaT1T2Controller : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DbPruebaContext _context;

    public VistaT1T2Controller(DbPruebaContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/VistaT1T2
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<VistaT1T2>>> GetVistaT1T2()
    {
        return await _context.VistaT1T2.ToListAsync();
    }
```

Luego ejecutar la API e invocar al controller

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva como orientación.